# issues with iOS Chart library

Tags: ios, swift, charts, mpandroidchart, ios-charts

I am using iOSCharts for swift by @**danielgindi** https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

So here is my data set

```
let dateArray = [26,27,28,29,30,01,02]
        let values = [11.0,5.0,0.0,0.0,4.0,1.0,0.0]

        var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

        for i in 0..<dateArray.count {
            let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }

        let data = BarChartData()
        let ds1 = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Hello")
        ds1.colors = [NSUIColor.red]
        data.addDataSet(ds1)




        self.barChartView.data = data

         self.barChartView.fitBars = true

        self.barChartView.gridBackgroundColor = NSUIColor.white

        self.barChartView.chartDescription?.text = ""
```

what I am expecting is this
[image]

but what I get is this

[image]

So as you can see the problems are below

1) Graph starting from one grid above, you see space at the bottom
2) xaxis labels are different, I am not sure how to set them.
3) I want to show x axis and y axis labels as int and not double.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the master version of the `BarchartViewController` in the ChartsDemo project, it implements both of your questions:

1) Left Axis alignment, see:

https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/ChartsDemo/Classes/Demos/BarChartViewController.m#L76

Specifically, you want to set the axisMinimum on the left Axis, for your example it'd be:

```
self.barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
```

2) X Axis values formatting.

This one is a little trickier.  You could borrow the DayAxisValueFormatter from ChartsDemo, but that's Objective-C code, so you need to be familiar with adding Objective-C to your project.

You could also get exactly what you asked for by making your view controller a IAxisValueFormatter, and implementing like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, IAxisValueFormatter {

    var dateArray: [Int] = [26,27,28,29,30,01,02] //member variable

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        return dateArray[i]
    }

    //edit:  forgot to say this earlier, you need to do this somewhere in your bar graph setup code
    self.barChwrtView.xAxis.formatter = self
}
```

It's up to you to keep dateArray and values in synch whenever you update your chart.

Answer (score 0):

Your second problem, the X label issue, is caused on this line:

let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])

The `x` value is being set just to `i` (as a Double), when I suspect you meant to set it to `Double(dateArray[i])`, like this:

let dateArray = [26,27,28,29,30,01,02]
        let values = [11.0,5.0,0.0,0.0,4.0,1.0,0.0]

```
var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

for i in 0..<dateArray.count {
    let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(dateArray[i]), y: values[i])
    dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
}
```

This code can be shorted with the use of `zip` and `map`:

```
let dataEntries = zip(dateArray, values).map(BarChartDataEntry.init(x:y:))
```

This code will pair up every date of `dateArray` with a value from `value`. Then, these pairs are transformed, by being passed into the `BarChartDataEntry.init(x:y:)` initializer. This technique is nice because it removes the need for `dataEntries` to be mutable.

Comment: Hey thanks, Can you help me out with first problem. Why there is gap below

Comment: barChartView.legend.enabled = false

Answer (score 0):

try `leftAxis.axisMinValue = 0.0`